# Graph API throttling limits for a multitenant app

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-service-principal

For a multi-tenant OAuth based enterprise application calling the Graph API where dooes the published app and tenant API throttling limits apply to:

1. the single global application and the "partner" tenant
2. each instance of the application (service principal) and "customer" tenant that has consented to the app
3. some other combination

I'm trying to understand if throttling limits are essentially counted to the "partner" app-tenant or the "customer" app-tenant or some combination.

Via DAP had an SP principle which encountered these throttling limits, not sure what would happen in a multi-tenant scenario

Answer (score 1):

All of the scenarios you mentioned might result in throttling, as well as others not mentioned. The specifics for when throttling occurs might be different for different endpoints in Microsoft Graph, and may change over time.

You can read mode about when throttling occurs, what you can do to avoid it, and what to do about it [Optimize network traffic with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/optimize-network-traffic/). It boils down to:

1. Throttling might occur for any request, there's no published algorithm.
2. Reduce the likelihood of throttling by avoiding unnecessarily complex or voluminous requests.
3. When (not if) you get throttled, back off the required amount of time before retrying.